# xslt2.0 unparsed-text with regexp

Tags: xml, regex, xslt-2.0, plaintext

I have plain text:
**input text**

```
ExternalEvent(GpiIn2: LOW->HI) - AirAction(Play)
AirLog
<log date="2012-07-22" Audio="123.wav" />
AirLog
```

When i used code xslt 2.0 transform:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="vText" select=
 "replace(unparsed-text('file:///c:/123.log'),'\r','')"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <document>
      <xsl:analyze-string select="$vText" regex="'\&lt;'">
         <xsl:non-matching-substring><xsl:sequence select="."/></xsl:non-matching-substring>
      </xsl:analyze-string>
  </document>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I got xml:

```
<document>
    ExternalEvent(GpiIn2: LOW-&gt;HI) - AirAction(Play)
    AirLog
    &lt;log date="2012-07-22" Audio="123.wav" /&gt;
    AirLog
</document>
```

Anybody, can told me, what i need add to regexp for have wellformed XML, likre are:

```
<document>
      <log date="2012-07-22" Audio="123.wav" >
</document>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using an XSLT 2.0 processor like XmlPrime or Saxon which already support functions in the W3C XPath 3.0 like `parse-xml-fragment` you can simply do

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="url1" select="'file:///c:/123.log'"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <document>
    <xsl:copy-of select="parse-xml-fragment(unparsed-text($url1))//log"/>
  </document>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```